# There was no endpoint listening at <SERVICE URL>

Tags: wcf, endpoint

There was no endpoint listening at  that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The App config is below.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="IApprovalBatchProcess">          
        </binding>       
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:131/ApprovalBatchProcess.svc"  
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="IApprovalBatchProcess"  
                contract="ApprovalServiceReference.IApprovalBatchProcess"          name="IApprovalBatchProcess" />
    </client>    
  </system.serviceModel>.
```

Comment: To access a WCF URL in console application , I am getting above error Message. Please any one assist me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First troubleshooting step is to paste that URL into a browser and see if you can get to it from that.

Comment: Hi... Theurl is working . Please find the  below.                                               
 svcutil.exe http://localhost:60222/ApprovalBatchProcess.svc?wsdl
You can also access the service description as a single file:

http://localhost:6022/ApprovalBatchProcess.svc?singleWsdl

Comment: Different port, though.

Comment: The Port No IS  http://localhost:60222/

Comment: Not in the config snippet above.

Comment: The Correct port is 60222 Only

Comment: The app config you give is the client configuration, and your server configuration also needs to be filled with corresponding attributes. In addition, the port on the client config is 131, and the service port you give is 60222, which needs to be unified.